# Services and resources for creating Android icon(s)

Tags: resource-recommendations, icon, mobile, interface-design

What services/resources, paid or otherwise, are available to android developers who want an icon designed for their mobile app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a template pack here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

as well as some pretty thorough guidelines for developing icons for the Droid. I would assume that anyone who could do web / graphic work could make icons for the Droid (it looks like they range from 19 x 19 px to 72 x 72 px). I don't know if there's anyone who's concentrating specifically on Droid icons (who knows - there could be) but someone who's got experience making other icons for UIs could probably make what you want fairly quickly.

BTW, it looks like they're looking for .png files as the final format, which should not present problems to any designer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was wondering what design services there are out there that could produce an affordable and acceptable icon.

Comment: @jrdioko, are you looking for business names?

Comment: @Jaips: Businesses or sites that provide this service (icon design to Android standards). Sorry I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for something that helps you with the guidelines, this is a useful tool based on a Google Project: 
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

It does everything in automatic so I would not recommend it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Grab a designer whose style you really like, see how much it would be for them to design an app icon for you, and get started :)

Check out dribbble.com Lot's of great people on there.